# ActionScript 3, rotating an object to one point then on completion another point

Tags: actionscript-3

I've been trying to make a dial go to a point and then on completion go to another point

```
function EGTdialpostition1():void
{
    EGTNeedle_mc.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, EGTdialpostition2);
    EGTNeedle_mc.speed = 2 
    EGTNeedle_mc.increment = 0.5
    EGTNeedle_mc.startRotation(179)
}
function EGTdialpostition2(evt:Event):void
{
    trace("The needle has stopped")
    EGTNeedle_mc.speed = 2 
    EGTNeedle_mc.increment = 0.5
    EGTNeedle_mc.startRotation(164)
}
EGTdialpostition1()
stage.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, EGTdialpostition2)
```

//when EGTdialpostition is called by the event listener the trace happens but nothing else to test the function i set up the event listener for a mouse click to call the function and it works.

I know there are hundreds of ways round this but I would like to know if there is a way to fix this, or is there something im doing wrong

Any help or advice would be gratefully recieved

Comment: Well, I would begin by renaming my functions to start with a lower-case letter (this is not C#) and the same goes for the instance/variable names - looks like you would have a class and a static call there. (<- this has nothing to do with your problem but it is something to think about). Now to your problem: What is that Event.COMPLETE there? When is it dispatched? What is EGTNeddle_mc? We need to see that class.

Comment: I agree with Fygo... I assume **EGTNeedle_mc** is a Class so more specifically we need to see the `function startRotation (arg : argType) : void;`. Also look at this for dispatching **[custom-made event](http://www.as3blog.org/2010/03/11/how-to-dispatch-a-custom-event/)**